# Having problems with getting my margin-top to be cross browser compatible/

Tags: html, css, margins

so for the HTML I have

```
<section id="slider">
    <div class="rslides_container">
  <ul class="rslides" id="slider1">
    <li><img src="images/IMG_5858.jpg" alt="The Process"></li>
    <li><img src="images/IMG_5642.jpg" alt="Pieces of a Quilt"></li>
    <li><img src="images/IMG_5764.jpg" alt="Here's Looking at You"></li>
    <li><img src="images/IMG_5847.jpg" alt="Which Way Do I Go"></li>
    <li><img src="images/IMG_5851.jpg" alt="Which Way Do I Go"></li>        
    <li><img src="images/IMG_5659.jpg" alt="Which Way Do I Go"></li>                
    <li><img src="images/IMG_5664.jpg" alt="Which Way Do I Go"></li>                        
  </ul>
</div>

</section>
```

and for the css I have

```
#slider
{
    width:585px;
    background-color:#e0e0e0;   
    padding:11px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-left:27px;
    margin-top:-621px;
}
```

any idea why in Chrome it is looking fine but in FF the margin-top is slightly higher and in IE it is even higher than FF and Chrome. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Could you please include a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that we can take a look at? Also change all of the images to a universal source so that we can see them.

Comment: @Geroy290 http://jsfiddle.net/vxZ73/ mind you I did not include the JS, but you can see that the grey box on the right that has the bulleted list is not showing as lining up with top grey box on the left. This needs to render the same in IE, FF, Chrome, Safari etc.

Comment: I just updated the code with a bit more content. Also having problems with the fonts rendering properly in different browsers. I have the @font-face set to what it should be but it doesn't seem to be picking up the changed font types. Will this only work if these font files are loaded to the FTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to wrap `aside` element in a div  and then give a float:left; and remove `positoin:absolute` and `margin:left` from `#slider` and use same margin properties you have used for `aside` element.

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ruworite/1/edit)**.

```
#slider
{
background-color:#e0e0e0;   
float:left;
margin:25px 0 0 40px;
padding:0 12px;
width:30%;
/*margin-left:370px;
margin-top:80px;
position:absolute;*/
}

.wrap{float:left;}/*contain all aside element*/
```

Comment: Is this answer helpful for you?

Comment: I did that and it actually made it worse.

Comment: Yes it didn't work unless I did something wrong. It moved the "slider" to inline with the aside boxes and moved it lower too. I also just updated the code with additional content in the JSFiddle

Comment: Ok I missed the part of wrapping the asides in a div. It works now thank you. Also having problems with the fonts rendering properly in different browsers. I have the @font-face set to what it should be but it doesn't seem to be picking up the changed font types. Will this only work if these font files are loaded to the FTP? Is there something wrong with that bit of the code too?

Comment: for the font face you should use woff format as well. yes you have to upload the custom font on your server as well an then use a font path when defining font in css file

Comment: so this won't work unless it is on the my server? Could I trouble you for the entire @font-face that I would use for one of font-faces in the css?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/ this URL will help you to solve your custom font problem.

Comment: yes you have to upload your custom font on the server as well.

Comment: if my solution works for you then you may accept this answer by giving a voting.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have enough "reputation" to do as such sorry.

Comment: I just asked for that so that in near future people have same problem can get benefited. upvote will also work and when have a repo. you can accept the answer by hitting the green check mark icon.

Comment: I meant currently I have not yet loaded any of the files to the my server, will the woff and otf, eot and svg fonts only work if they are residing on the server or should they be able to work locally?

Comment: I loaded everything to the FTP for testing purposes even with the fonts loaded in it, it is not reading the fonts file types that I converted them to (EOT, OTF, SVG, WOFF) etc. Any suggestions on this?
Here is the URL http://www.inertiastreak.com/polpette/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
display:block;
float:left;
```

Try replacing the two lines with

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: that worked but Google chrome is still a few pixels to high unlike FF and IE